# Will I be judged on judgment day for not avoiding my family's haram business?

Tags: halal-haram, work, family

I live in the USA and I'm 18 years old. My father is retired from work and my brothers have a store which is haram. They sell alcohol and lottery. I tried to convince them to stop it but they won't listen. They don't even pray. I told my father that I want to leave the store. He told me, no even though I found halal and better job. He even told me if you leave the store I will not want you in my house. And in NYC it's hard to find affordable place.

Will I be judged on judgment day for not avoiding my family's haram business?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question with a straightforward answer in the Quran itself:

> "Indeed, those whom the angels take away while they are wronging themselves, they (the angels) ask, ‘*What state were you in?*’ They reply, ‘*We were weak in the land.*’ They say, ‘***Was not Allah’s earth vast enough so that you might migrate in it?***’ The refuge of such shall be hell, and it is an evil destination.
>
> Except the weak among the men, women and children, who have neither access to any means nor are guided to any way.
>
> Maybe Allah will excuse them, for Allah is all-excusing, all-forgiving.
>
> **Whoever migrates in the way of Allah will find many havens and plenitude in the earth.** And whoever leaves his home migrating toward Allah and His Apostle, and is then overtaken by death, his reward shall certainly fall on Allah, and Allah is all-forgiving, all-merciful." (4:97-100)

If you die in this state without having fixed your ways, your excuse that you were weak or forced will not be accepted from you. Seeing as you live in a Western country, you don't have the excuse that you were forced to stay or that your means were prevented.

Economic difficulties can and will be alleviated by Allah if you choose to migrate away from your house, and even if the difficulties are not alleviated and even if you die in poverty you will be given a reward promised by Allah in the hereafter.

Answer (score 0):

From Quran verses **6:164**, **14:51**, **31:33** (relevant for your specific case), **35:18**, **99:7**, **99:8**, I understand that everyone will be responsible from whatever they did (good or bad), and only from whatever they did and no one else's deeds, regardless of whether they are so small deeds.

Additionally, in the light of verses **16:25** and **29:13**, I understand that those who lead others to sin, those who provide tools for the purpose of sinning, those who have an effect on others' sins (e.g. producing or selling alcohol, recording and distributing inappropriate videos, raising a band of thieves and having them steal things from others, developing a technology the whole purpose of which is to harm people, etc.), will also be responsible for their part of causing those sins committed by others (not for the sins committed by others, but for leading others to commit sins).

Please think of the verses in the above two paragraphs as a whole, you will understand they do not contradict. To clarify my point: Anyone who leads others to sin will be responsible for the sin of "leading others to sin" multiplied by how many people that person lead to sin. That person will not be responsible for the sins committed by those who committed them, as they will be responsible for their own sins.

Back to your specific case:

Unless your family is physically holding you as a prisoner (e.g. locking doors on you) and controlling your body physically (e.g. they have shackles or handcuffs) and forcing you pysically (e.g. they are controlling your body parts like your hands, feet, mouth to sell/serve alcohol), you should not continue with that business. If that means you will be kicked out of the house, trust in Allah, as It owns all this universe, your father and you, and pray and have hope that It will provide you a halal means for earning your life. Abandon that business immediately today my brother, you won't regret in the long term.

Anyone who continued to produce, deliver, sell, serve and drink alcohol, will most probably prefer dying in the street from poverty, rather than continuing their business, when they see the grand hardships of the Judgment day.

May Allah forgive our sins.

In case you will have economic hardship by being kicked out of your house, I would suggest seeking a Muslim community in your location and ask for their advice and help if possible, to maybe provide a place to stay and/or a job to work at. I am pretty sure there won't be a shortage of Muslims who would gladly help a young person in your case.

**TO EDITORS:** Please do not add links or insert verses in my answers, where I clearly mention a verse number as reference. I am not linking to any site/resource or not including the verse words in a language in my answers because I am leaving the reader to choose whichever language and translation of Quran they choose to refer to, or directly read it in Arabic if they understand that language.

Comment: It seems uncooperative to get rid of these links which facilitate easy access to the relevant verses.  The reader is not inhibited from reading alternative translations, etc., of the Qur'an because of these links.

Answer (score 0):

No, i think you will be not be accountable for this because you are not doing this but it's better for you to migrate towards any other place where you should work halal.